# iOS Parse: Remove pointer without removing object

Tags: ios, parse-platform

In Parse, I have an object which has a key that is an array of pointers to other objects. How do I delete one of the pointers without deleting the entire array and without deleting the actual object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the removeObject:forKey: method of PFObject, it removes the item from your array but won't delete the pointer.

That's obj-c, btw, I'm not familiar with the Swift SDK.

You should read into the API Guide a bit for PFObjects and PFQueries. It'll answer a lot of questions you have before you ask them.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/removeObjectForKey:

Comment: Used removeObject:forKey: to remove the pointer on one object, but it removed the pointed to object as well. Then I realized that only one object was pointing to the pointed object. When I had two objects pointing to the same object and used removeObject:forKey: on one of the objects, it removed the pointer but left the object. Not what I expected, but that's exactly what I wanted. So yeah, removeObject:forKey: is the answer. And it looks like the pointed to object is also deleted when nothing is left pointing to it. I have no idea what magic is in place to make that happen, but I like it.